# Place xlabel below node in DiagrammeR / Graphviz

Tags: r, graphviz, quarto, diagrammer, systemdynamics

I want to create system dynamics graphics for a course material that I write in Quarto, ideally with Graphviz (R package DiagrammeR). To be as close as possible to the standards, I want to use a "flow symbol", for example an hourglass character. In the attempt below I use a special character, but a method with two triangles would also be fine. The problem is now, how to place an additional label below the flow symbol. I tried three different ideas:

1. use an edge directly from A to B and somehow add the hourglass in the middle,
2. add an additional overlapping edge directly from A to B, but then the arrows get curved to avoid overlap,
3. use `xlabel` that seems to be the easiest (see below) even if it needs tricks to reduce the font size. However, I want to have the `xlabel` "growth" in the middle and a little bit lower, below the hourglass.

Here is my code:

```r
library(DiagrammeR)

graph_code <- '
digraph {
  graph [rankdir = "LR"]
  
  node [shape = rect]
  A  B
  
  node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, fontsize=20, fixedsize=true, forcelabels=true]
  C [label="&#10710;", xlabel=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="8">growth</FONT>>]
  
  A -> C [dir = none, color = "blue"]
  C -> B [dir = left, color = "blue"]

}
'

grViz(graph_code)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combines the **label** & **xlabel** into an html table.

```
digraph {
  graph [rankdir = "LR"]  
  node [shape = rect]
  A  B
  
  node [shape=none, Xfontsize=20]
  // the height may need to be tweaked, based on actual fonts used
  C [label=<<table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="12"></td></tr><tr><td><FONT POINT-SIZE="20">&#10710;</FONT></td></tr><tr><td>growth</td></tr></table>>]
  
  A -> C [dir = none, color = "blue" headclip=false]
  C -> B [dir = left, color = "blue" tailclip=false]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: This is a possible solution with the small disadvantage that the height needs to be fine-tuned by hand to make the notch exactly centered.