# How to center text in custom html-style GraphViz/DiagrammeR node?

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

Following the helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78203709/3677576) of a previous question, there is still an unresolved issue, that the hourglass symbol (i.e. the text in custom node) is not centered, so that vertical edges are not in the middle. I tried also different html-style centering options, but with no success. Any method or a completely different approach would be welcome.

```r
library(DiagrammeR)

graph <- "
digraph logistic_growth {

  graph [rankdir = 'LR', bgcolor='none', fontsize=10]

  node [shape = circle, fontsize=8, penwidth=0.7, fontname='Open Sans']
   r [xlabel=' intrinsic growth rate']
   K [xlabel=' carrying capacity']

  node [shape = box, penwidth=2]
    N [label='Population N']

  node [shape = octagon, width='', penwidth=0.5, style='rounded', fixedsize=25]
    Source Sink

  node [shape=plaintext, width=0.2, height=0.2]
    growth [label=<<table cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td height='10'></td></tr><tr><td><FONT POINT-SIZE='20'>&#10710;</FONT></td></tr><tr><td>growth</td></tr></table>>]

  edge [penwidth=1.5]
    Source -> growth [dir = none, color = 'blue' headclip=false]
    growth -> N      [dir = left, color = 'blue' tailclip=false]
    N -> Sink

  edge [penwidth=0.7, tailport = 'n', headport = 'n', constraint = false, color=tomato]
    N -> growth

  edge [penwidth=0.7, tailport = 'e', headport = 'n', constraint = false, color=tomato]
    r -> growth
    K -> growth
}
"

grViz(graph)
```

[image: digraph of a logistic model]

Comment: This seems to be a font & format issues (ugh)  Questions: what output format(s), on one computer or many, if many, what OSs? Are you open to pipelining multiple Graphviz engines? Are you open to using an image for hourglass/growth?

Comment: I tested it in R with the DiagrammeR package on Windows 10. I agree that checking  other systems makes sense, e.g. with original command line Graphviz on Windows and Linux (Fedora or Ubuntu). And, yes, I am open to use pipelining multiple engines or an image, ideally svg, but bitmap (e.g. png) will also do.

Comment: Tested it with the command line version of dot (Windows 10) and default font, and the problem persisted. Similar on Fedora with command line and svg-output, but horizontal offset somewhat less. With png: worked on Linux without offset :-) but on Windows another issue: horizontal alignment is ok, but special character is not printed. Instead of the hourglass I get a rectangle with the character code.

Comment: After some trial and error, I think there is a bug with the hourglass symbol on Windows. Other letters, e.g. "x" are horizontally centered. So let's try an image for the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a convoluted but solid solution.

- run **dot** (format=**dot**) with a simple "growth" node.  **label=""**, **xlabel="growth"**, and a new attribute **hourglass=1** (yep, Graphviz allows user-defined attributes)
- run the output into a **gvpr** program (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) that will

  - move the **xlabel**
  - define a new (bogus) edge with a path (**pos**) that we will contort into the hourglass shape
- run that output into **neato -n2 ...** that will produce the final, complete image
  Result:
  [image]

dot input:

```
digraph logistic_growth {

  graph [rankdir = "LR", XXbgcolor="none", fontsize=10]

  node [shape = circle, fontsize=8, penwidth=0.7, fontname="Open Sans"]
   r [xlabel=" intrinsic growth rate"]
   K [xlabel=" carrying capacity"]

  node [shape = box, penwidth=2]
    N [label="Population N"]

  node [shape = octagon, width="", penwidth=0.5, style="rounded", fixedsize=25]
    Source Sink

  node [shape=plaintext, width=0.2, height=0.2]
    growth [label="" xlabel="\N" hourglass=1]  // any undefined attribute name

  edge [penwidth=1.5]
    Source -> growth [dir = none, color = "blue" headclip=false]
    growth -> N      [dir = left, color = "blue" tailclip=false]
    N -> Sink

  edge [penwidth=0.7, tailport = "n", headport = "n", constraint = false, color=tomato]
    N -> growth:n

  edge [penwidth=0.7, tailport = "e", headport = "n", constraint = false, color=tomato]
    r -> growth:n
    K -> growth:n
}
```

**gvpr** program (save as hourglass.gvpr):

```
BEGIN{
  int i;
  edge_t hGlass;
  string x1, y1, x2, y2, pp1, p2, p3, p4, segment1, segment2, segment3, segment4;
}

N[hourglass=="1"]{
  // first, move xlabel
  oldXLP=xlp;
  xlp=(string)$.X + ","+ (string) yOf($.xlp);
  // create a very bogus edge that will become the hourglass figure
  // need to convert inches to points then divide by 2 == *72/2 == *36
  x1=(string)($.X-(((float)$.width/2)*72));
  x2=(string)($.X+(((float)$.width/2)*72));  
  y1=(string)($.Y-(((float)$.height/2)*72));
  y2=(string)($.Y+(((float)$.height/2)*72));
  p1=x1 + "," + y1 + " ";
  p2=x2 + "," + y1 + " ";
  p3=x1 + "," + y2 + " ";
  p4=x2 + "," + y2 + " ";
  segment1=p1 + p1 + p1 + p2;
  segment2=p2 + p2 + p3;
  segment3=p3 + p3 + p4;
  segment4=p4 + p4 + p1;
  hGlass=edge($, $, "");           //$.name + "->" + $.name);
  hGlass.pos=segment1 + segment2 + segment3 + segment4;
  hGlass.color="black";
}
```

Finally, the command line (Linux) (Windows can be broken into separate steps)

```
dot myFile.gv |gvpr -cfhourglass.gvpr |neato -n2 -Tsvg >myFile.svg
```

Comment: Quite an effort (i.e. your effort :-) for such a simple graphics, but worked perfectly. Yesterday, I made a "flow symbol" in Inkscape, but failed to intergrate it.